# Basic prerequisite (topics) to read current research in Diophantine equation for an independent researcher

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, diophantine-equations, research

I have completed studying Galois theory, Fermat's Last Theorem for Regular prime and some number theoretic complex analysis (prime number theorem), and basic linear forms in logarithm.

What else should I complete reading to be eligible to read contemporary literature in Diophantine Equation (Exponential) ?

My graduation was in engineering, so I am from non-math (I mean serious math!) background, and I am not going to a university in near future, but wish to conduct research as an independent researcher.

There might be a lack of specification in  my question, so if possible, adjust your answer according to that, also feel free to edit.

Comment: Try looking at papers at a number theory journal, such as Journal of Number Theory, Acta Arithmetica, International Journal of Number Theory, and Algebra and Number Theory and see if you can understand them. If not, then check their references and read those, continue until you reach foundational texts written in a language that you can understand

Comment: The modern study is based a lot upon algebraic geometry. So the more of this you know the better.

Comment: This book (*Rational Points on Varieties* by the irrepressible Bjorn Poonen) contains a lot of the prerequisites you would need in case you go the algebro-geometric route: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf

Comment: However, the learning curve for the geometric track is both steep and long (a true *via longissima*). The "pay-off" of your studies (meaning concrete results and papers of your own) would probably be greater if you wouldn't concentrate exclusively on all that high-falutin stuff, and set your sights more on analytic number theory, additive combinatorics, recreational problem solving... There is always a severe danger of involving yourself in massive propaedeutic studies, without the slightest guarantee of the possibility of contributing something of your own. Just my two cents...

Comment: I don't think there is a coherent field of mathematics called Diophantine equations. It's like classification of finite simple groups: a statement about objects that are very easy to define but its proof consists of numerous subcases involving absolutely disparate techniques that have nothing to do with each other. I expect that the vast majority of diophantine equations can not be meaningfuly attacked with the techniques of algebraic geometry, Galois representations and automorphic forms. So there are no well-defined prerequisites.

Comment: @crispr Okay, in that case, plz suggests some specific ways from your point of view.

Comment: No, I mean for a general diophantine equation there are no specific ways (or rather I suspect no human alive knows any specific ways).

Comment: @RP_ Thanks for your valuable comment, could u know of any blog that helps for this specific subject for  building up basics to study the topic or to know about the topic?

Comment: Well I was basically saying that, to my mind, there are better ways of spending your time, *especially* with regard to the algebro-geometric route. But if you do want to press ahead against all odds, you could look at this question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369433/reference-request-diophantine-equations

Comment: @RP_ what better ways, please share.. liked your comment, guess it would be helpful.

Comment: @Andrew That is not for me to decide. I was just saying: this particular area (let's call it Diophantine geometry) requires massive preparatory studies, and it's far from guaranteed that you'll get your investment back. So depending on your own taste, the conclusion to draw from this could be: (1) disregard what I'm saying completely and persevere; (2) still study Diophantine equations, but from the analytic or combinatoric (or whatever) side; (3) do something else in mathematics; (4) do something else entirely. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, the keywords for the type of number theory you're interested in are "Diophantine approximation" and "transcendental number theory."  Are you aware of Florian Luca's article on [Exponential Diophantine Equations](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-12558-5_4.pdf)?  If not, that might be a good place to start.  You might also like M. Ram Murty and Purusottam Rath's book *Transcendental Numbers*.

Getting to the research frontier is always a tricky business.  Michel Waldschmidt's *Diophantine Approximation on Linear Algebraic Groups* will give you a sense of what some of the major open problems in the subject are, but that's a very demanding book.  There undoubtedly exist lower-hanging fruit, but it may be hard to find such fruit without an experienced advisor to guide you.

Comment: maybe it is useful to remark that even ignoring the issue of an advisor, one valuable source of information that a "normal" graduate student has access to and an independent researcher doesn't is a group of peers at roughly the same level of mathematical understanding as you that you see on a day-to-day basis. I think for many people the perspective of other people allows them to re-gauge their views on what is important/difficult and to lose any misconceptions sooner than they might otherwise.

Comment: +1 But I don't know how I feel about referring an independent (that is unpaid) researcher to an article behind a paywall, sold by price-gouging publishing houses. I would try to e-mail the author and request a preprint copy from him, if I were the OP.

Comment: @RP_ : Is it behind a paywall? I thought it wasn't, because I am able to view it from a machine that isn't registered to my institution, but maybe I have some cookies in my browser or something.

Comment: @TimothyChow I think that must be the case. The page I'm getting says I can buy the chapter for 27,20 EUR (which isn't that bad comparatively speaking, but still).

Comment: Is [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=khCTDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA267&ots=kBKAzLRxbk&sig=AGGwCaNjHZ1tKp5xzNVUvADe1o0#v=onepage&q&f=false) any better?