# Reference request: Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I am looking for a textbook, or preferably lectures, on the subject of Diophantine equations. I am familiar with the basic principles of modular arithmetic, conics and the Hasse Principle, and the basics of elliptic curves, Mordell's Theorem etc (though I'm not up to the point where I can understand the proof).

What I need is something that takes me beyond the basics. Something which will teach me the advanced theory, and also teach me about diophantine surfaces (not just curves).

Comment: I don’t think a single textbook or lecture series will provide you with a robust picture of the “advanced theory” of half of the topics you mentioned in the post. For example, Hasse principle is still a subject of intense research.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just looking for anything which can push forward my knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be a good choice for someone who (like yourself) is already superficially acquainted with some of the definitions and methods of Diophantine geometry:

- Marc Hindry, Joseph H. Silverman -- *Diophantine Geometry: An Introduction*, Graduate Texts in Mathematics **201**, Springer (2000), https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1210-2.

The following two are great expository articles (especially the first), which provided me with plenty of inspiration back in the day:

- Mazur, Barry. Arithmetic on curves. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 14 (1986), no. 2, 207--259. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183553167
- Mazur, Barry. On the passage from local to global in number theory ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9307231))

Henri Darmon has a couple of nice articles on the topic of rational points on curves:

- Rational points on curves ([link](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/12.Clay/paper.pdf))
- Rational points on modular elliptic curves ([link](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/36.NSF-CBMS/chapter.pdf))

Anthony Varilly-Alvarado has a number of very good introductions to the topic of rational points on different types of surfaces:

- Lectures on the Arithmetic of del Pezzo surfaces ([link](https://math.rice.edu/%7Eav15/Files/LeidenLectures.pdf))
- Arithmetic of K3 surfaces ([link](https://math.rice.edu/%7Eav15/Files/AWS2015Notes.pdf))

Alexei Skorobogatov taught a course in 2013 on the topic of rational points on surfaces and higher-dimensional varieties. The notes strike a great balance between accessibility and generality:

- Arithmetic geometry: rational points ([link](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Eanskor/arith_geom_files/TCCnotes.pdf))

Then there are these notes by Yonatan Harpaz on rational points on elliptic surfaces:

- Rational points on elliptic fibrations -- Course notes ([link](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Eharpaz/IHP_course_notes.pdf))

Finally (for now), Brendan Hassett has a nice article on the topic of potential density of rational points on varieties, which is very interesting as well:

- Potential density of rational points on
  algebraic varieties ([link](https://www.math.brown.edu/%7Ebhassett/papers/budapest/budalect.pdf))

Answer (score 7):

E.g.

- *Number Theory: Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations*, Graduate Texts in Mathematics **239**, https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-49923-9; and
- *Number Theory: Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools*, Graduate Texts in Mathematics **240**, https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-49894-2

by Henri Cohen.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to get far in the modern theory without some algebraic geometry.

This is the approach taken in the book:

- Bjorn Poonen, *Rational points on varieties*, Graduate Studies in Mathematics **186** (2017), [publisher page](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-186), [Author pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in applications of Baker's method, Schmidt's subspace theorem etc., then you might like the following recent books by Evertse and Győry:

- *Discriminant equations in Diophantine number theory*, New Mathematical Monographs, 32, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2017.
- *Unit equations in Diophantine number theory*, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 146, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2015.

Answer (score 3):

To the books mentioned above I would add one more:

- Rational and Nearly Rational Varieties (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics) by J. Kollár, K. E. Smith, and A. Corti.

The authors present a more or less elementary approach to the rationality questions using a mix of classical and modern methods.